# What is the pipe character "x|y)" in the case statement?

Tags: linux, shell-script

In a script `/etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd` in my system, I find statements like this:

```
case "$ADDRFAM" in
  inet|NetworkManager) ;;
  *) exit 0
esac

case "$METHOD" in
static|dhcp|NetworkManager) ;;
*) exit 0
esac
```

The pipe character `|` seems like the logic "or", but I can't find this rule in the guide. I can only find `|` used as the command pipe and the "bitwise or" for the arithmetic integer.

Can anyone tell me what's the usage in this case?

Comment: It is called 'vertical bar character', not 'pipe character'.

Comment: @uprego It is called ['vertical line'](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/007c/index.htm), not 'vertical bar character'.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the pattern clauses of a case statement, `|` means precisely `or`.

From the [bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs) on `case`:

> The syntax of the case command is:

```
case word in [ [(] pattern [| pattern]…) command-list ;;]… esac
```

> The ‘|’ is used to separate multiple patterns, and the ‘)’ operator terminates a pattern list.

Comment: So as I understand it, it's used as the `or` only in the patterns, right?

Comment: @platinor: In arithmetic expansions (`$((...))` or, in bash and some other shells, the command `((...))`), `|` is the "bitwise-or" operator. (Eg. `echo $((18|3))` outputs `19`). In bash, if the `extglob` shell option is enabled (as by default), then `|` may be used in an "extended glob" pattern to indicate alternation ("or"). See http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Pattern-Matching